# Conseguir dados de uma coluna específica em CSV

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou com uma dúvida em um exercício. 
Tenho uma tabela aonde eu preciso obter o resultados somente de uma coluna.

os dados estao da seguinte forma:
['2017-01-01 00:27:45', '2017-01-01 00:31:13', '208', 'Damen Ave & Chicago Ave', 'Damen Ave & Division St', 'Subscriber', 'Male', '1982.0']]

no caso preciso obter o gênero (masculino e feminino das 20 primeiras amostras)...
Da forma que estou fazendo não consigo obter somente esta coluna e acabo puxando a linha 6 toda....

aguem pode me da uma ajuda???

[image: Segue meu código]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5zuo.jpg)

Comment: Não coloque código como imagem, ao invés disso coloque como texto formatando com `Ctrl + k` ou com o botão `{}` do editor da pergunta

Answer (score -1):

Juliana aconselho voce a utilizar a biblioteca **Pandas** para trabalhar com o CSV.

Nesse caso voce poderia seguir da seguinte maneira:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Depois de importada a biblioteca, voce deve carregar o arquivo. No caso abaixo como voce não informou o cabeçalho, deixei a flag *HEADER* como '*None*'

```
df = pd.read_csv('CAMINHO DO SEU ARQUIVO', header= None)
```

Após isso o arquivo já foi carregado, e você pode utilizar o comando `df.info()` para ver como ficou.

no exemplo que você deu para obter os dados da Coluna que representa o gênero basta escrever o comando:

```
print(df[6])
```

Segue imagem com uma base de exemplo que montei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A biblioteca PANDAS é muito utilizada recomendo esse [LINK](http://minerandodados.com.br/index.php/2017/09/26/python-para-analise-de-dados/), como um conteúdo introdutório

Comment: Muito obrigada Clayton!!! Vou tentar mais tarde quando chegar em casa.